# Smart Home networking questions?

Tags: discussion, scope

Are IoT related question allowed, or going to be allowed, on superuser.com?

For example, I would like to know if a Google Nest thermostat can be made to work with a Samsung SmartThings Hub.

I know there is a hacking culture related to these things, but isn't there any place to ask on Stack Exchange?

Technically, the answers for such questions aren't really that different to what gets asked here already.

There are already seems to be lots of X10 questions on superuser.com and X10 can be regarded a precurser to IoT devices.

Comment: It depends. Windows has an IoT version those would be on question, but RP2 questions would be better at the RP SE.  It depends.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'd really think this feels like something outside our scope. While these devices are 'smart' and do have some sort of computer in them.

X10 and IOT probably should be on topic *if* there's a computer involved somewhere.

> electronic devices, media players, cell phones or smart phones, except insofar as they interface with your computer,

Are not on topic here.

I'd say no based on my read of the rules, but as with these things, I welcome a contrary viewpoint.